# Convert int* to int, error for stack as a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

```cpp
template <class Type>
Type stackType<Type>::top() const {
     assert(stackTop != nullptr);  // if stack is empty, terminate the program
     return stackTop->list;  // return the element of the stack 
}
```

Error:

```
stackTypeY.h: In instantiation of 'Type stackType<Type>::top() const [with Type = int]': 
testStack.cpp:22:31:   required from here
stackTypeY.h:129:22: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]       
     return stackTop->list;  // return the element of the stack
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: apparently, the type of `stackTop->list` is an `int*` (a pointer), not `int`. For further assistance, show a [mcve]

Comment: The assertion is also not compelling enough. For this to work, not only does `stackTop`  (whatever that is) not have to be null, so also goes `stackTop->list` (and of course, the latter properly dereferenced). What little code you bothered to show suggests there is one-too-many levels of indirection in whatever mysterious implementation you've contrived.

Comment: It makes perfect sense for `stackTop->list` to be a pointer. What doesn't make sense is why it is an `int*` pointer, when the question is about a linked list, so one would expect some kind of `node*` pointer instead, where `node` is a type that holds an `int` data field. Sounds more like `stackTop->list` is likely a dynamic array rather than a linked list.